# Objective-C, Accessing Objects in Storyboards OSX

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, storyboard, xib

I'm currently transitioning from `.nibs` and `.xibs` to the more recently available `.storyboard` format. Normally in my `.nib` I'm able to have an `Object` at the top level which any view or window can access, however, using the `.storyboard` this doesn't seem to be the case. It seems that objects that were once able to be placed with AppDelegate now have be placed within the ViewController which contains the View trying to access it. How can I change my Object so that it is globally accessible as it once was?

`Object` is accessable globally:

[image]

`Object` can only be accessed if it's within the ViewController:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting the object in the Application Scene?

Comment: Yes, I tried putting it there, and even within the Window Controller Scene. It's not able to be accessed or connected using Connections Inspector.